# Concatenate id on "create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, concatenation, string-concatenation

- Ruby 2.1
- Rails 4.2

I need to generate (by concatenation) a code (which contains the product id) on new records.
The problem is that the record must be created to have a id. So I can't generate the code on "create" because de id don't exists yet. I'm stuck.

So far it works, but only on update.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :generate_code

  private

  def generate_code
    tag = tags.map(&:name).join(", ").first(2)
    self.code = ("#{category_id} #{tag} #{id} #{glaze.code}").parameterize
  end

end
```

How to create a new record and, at the same time, concatenate your id on "code"?

**Update:**

I need it on update too.

**The final solution is:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :generate_code
  private

  def generate_code
    tag = tags.first.name.first(2)
    update_column(:code, ("#{category_id}" + "#{tag}" + "#{id}" + "#{glaze.code}").parameterize.upcase)
  end
end
```

Comment: You could have a "partial code" which does not contains the "id" of the record, and when you want to access to the "full code" of the record the model would compute the real full code with the partial one + the id.

Comment: It would be nice but I need the entire code for search.

Comment: you could also use the `after_create` callback. This way it is only created once and does not interfere with the `save` at all. e.g. `after_create :generate_code` and then instead of `self.code = ` use `update_attribute(:code, "#{category_id} #{tag} #{id} #{glaze.code}")`

Comment: a side question, what's the `.first(2)` for ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady to add the two first letters from tag in the code. E.g. a "cup" tag become CU, "plate" become PL and so on.

Comment: processing all tags is kinda inefficient for this, wouldn't something like this work `tags.first.name.first(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could Try something like this. This will generate a new code after creation (Part 1 issue where you have no id) and before update (Part 2 issue which works fine as a before because you already have an id)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :generate_code
  before_update :generate_code
  private

  def generate_code
    tag = tags.map(&:name).join(", ").first(2)
    if changed?
      self.code = "#{category_id} #{tag} #{id} #{glaze.code}"
    else
      update_attribute(:code,"#{category_id} #{tag} #{id} #{glaze.code}")
    end
  end
end
```

As @MohammadAbuShady mentioned this should also work as it is a direct DB edit with no callbacks or validations

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :generate_code
  private

  def generate_code
    tag = tags.first.name.first(2)
    update_column(:code, "#{category_id} #{tag} #{id} #{glaze.code}")
  end
end
```

Comment: why not just make it just `after_save`, wouldn't that probably be the same

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady no because `update_attribute` will call `save` again which would create an infinite loop. neither `after_create` or `before_update` will cause any overlapping issues with `save`.

Comment: `update_attribute` shouldn't trigger callbacks as far as i know

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady it does not trigger `validations` but `save(false)`  still triggers `save` and `update_attribute` calls `save(false)` [Docs for what triggers callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#running-callbacks)

Comment: ah ok, so it's `update_columns`, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thank you for that I will edit my answer to append your solution.

Comment: also `save(false)` doesn't work on rails 4, it's `save(validate: false)` now

Comment: @engineersmnky Mohammad maybe be right because I'm having the same error as after_save callback: **stack level too deep**.

Comment: @maiconsanson I do not have an `after_save` callback so there is an issue with you code in this case. Please review your code vs mine.

Comment: @engineersmnky after_save was the first answer given by infused user. Both give the same error. I will trying all the suggestions with calm and I will back in minutes to feedback the solution.

Comment: @maiconsanson I see the issue now an have updated my answer accordingly. Issue is that before_update is now being called infinitely. I have changed the code to use `self.code` for `before_update` and `update_attribute` for `after_create`. but this seems kind of hackish I would go with Mohammad solution of `update_column`.

Comment: @engineersmnky I will go with Mohammad too. Thank you both, it works on create and update as expected.